# Need to convert (x,y) points stored in SQL Server as binary image to float array at query time

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, spotfire

`(position, load)` points are being stored in SQL Server as an `image`. Each time the machine strokes, one record is created to store this position/load plot along with other data.

I need to convert the 'image' into numbers for analysis. I plan to do the analysis in Spotfire, so any Spotfire features can be used in the solution.

I have a C# program which queries the data from SQL and converts it to CSV; however, I want a way to skip this step directly query the points for viewing/analysis in Spotfire.

This C# works and does what I want. How can I use this (or some variant) to process the data on query from SQL so that users don't run a separate "converter" console app before opening their Spotfire file?

```
// Return a list of points from an array of bytes:
public static IList<PositionLoadPoint> GetPositionLoadPoints(byte[] bytes)
{
     IList<PositionLoadPoint> result = new List<PositionLoadPoint>();
     int midIndex = bytes.Length / 2;

     for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i += 4)
     {
         byte[] load = new byte[4];
         byte[] position = new byte[4];

         Array.Copy(bytes, i, load, 0, 4);
         Array.Copy(bytes, midIndex + i, position, 0, 4);

         var point = new PositionLoadPoint(BitConverter.ToSingle(load, 0),
                                           BitConverter.ToSingle(position, 0));

        result.Add(point);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Why are you storing this data as `image` in the first place? Why not use 2 individual columns and cut out all of this conversion code.

Comment: An old 3rd party software controls the database. I’m just an engineer trying to pull data from it.  But I appreciate the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [CLR Table-Valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-table-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017) to run that C# code and translate the binary data into a resultset.

A CLR TVF has an "init" method that returns a collection, and then SQL will run your "FillRow" method for each member of the returned collection.  The FillRow method translates the object into a "row" of output paramaters.  EG:

```
using System;  
using System.Data.Sql;  
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;  
using System.Collections;  
using System.Data.SqlTypes;  
using System.Diagnostics;  

public class TabularEventLog  
{  
    [SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]  
    public static IEnumerable InitMethod(String logname)  
    {  
        return new EventLog(logname).Entries;    
    }  

    public static void FillRow(Object obj, out SqlDateTime timeWritten, out SqlChars message, out SqlChars category, out long instanceId)  
    {  
        EventLogEntry eventLogEntry = (EventLogEntry)obj;  
        timeWritten = new SqlDateTime(eventLogEntry.TimeWritten);  
        message = new SqlChars(eventLogEntry.Message);  
        category = new SqlChars(eventLogEntry.Category);  
        instanceId = eventLogEntry.InstanceId;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have consulted my IT pro, and we think this will work. He's going to do the implementation next week. I am going to mark as correct right now.   I am mainly an SO lurker; thank you for your time and thanks to the community. I have learned a lot here.